# Socket#getOutputStream#write freezes current thread

Tags: java

I believe that I'm making some really simple mistake, but I can't seem to work it out.
The client connects to the server without a problem. But when I try to send client a message through socket.getOutputStream().write('☺'); It freezes current thread. And the only way to unfreeze is to exit the client.

Comment: What do you mean "freezes". Yes the thread is supposed to be blocking as it's a blocking call.

Comment: I mean it pauses that thread. And it never resumes.

Comment: Would be easier if you post some more relevant code

Comment: @AbhijeetSoni The only code to post is socket.getOutputStream().write('☺');

Answer (score -1):

The problem was, that I was creating ServerSocket through SSLSocketFactory.